# in react native, how can I scroll tab view vertically like 'react-native-scrollable-tab-view'

Tags: react-native, scrollview, vertical-scrolling

react native, like the pictures below, the left part and right part is both scrollable, and when left tab is tab and right part follows, it's like 'react-native-scrollable-tab-view', but vertically, any suggestions will be helpful, thanks~

[example pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pw92c.jpg)

[example pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95K5T.png)

Comment: For that, you have to make custom view using Flatlist as the Left view with tabs options and another right side view with grid list or custom flat list.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but the 'grid list' you mentioned, is there a third-party component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look as [this PR](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-tab-view/pull/418) which gives vertical tab bar capability to [react-native-tab-view](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-tab-view).

Since it's created long ago and not merged, you might have to apply those changes on top of the current master branch to start using.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, it's close, but the right part of the view is not horizontal scroll but vertically, will have a look at the 'react-native-tab-view'.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe how you break down the UI in mind is clouding your judgement.

Seeing the example pics, I think they are more like two components.

The right component is a SectionList.
The left component is a ScrollView with just buttons with labels of section titles of the right component. The onPress() of these buttons just calls scrollToLocation() of the SectionList to programmatically scroll to the the respective section.